# Setting Up SSO and WebIdentity in MobileFirst Platform

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, single-sign-on

I am trying to make an app using Ionic in Mobile First.

The web application is has got both sso and WebIdentity(LDAP) for the login functionality....

How to approach for the Hybrid Mobile App?

Comment: What is your IBM MobileFirst version?

Comment: Mobilefirst Version 7

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe there is direct relation between using LDAP in IBM MobileFirst Platform and using SSO in IBM MobileFirst Platform.

SSO in MFP allows you to automatically login to app2 if you have already logged-in in app1.

So assuming your are able to login to app1 via LDAP (which is server-side anyway, to check your credentials against a list of users), and assuming you have correctly set-up both apps for SSO, it should work.

Read about setting up SSO: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_device_single_sign_on.html